# How to Return Nested Values from Complicated JSON API

Tags: python, json, api-design

I am setting up a weather camera which will provide a live stream of the current conditions outside, but I also would like to overlay continuously updated weather conditions (temperature, wind speed/direction, current weather) from a local National Weather Service weather station, from a browser API source provided in JSON format.

I have had success extracting the desired values from a different API source using a Python script I wrote; however long story short that API source is unreliable. Therefore I am using API from the official National Weather Service ASOS station at my nearby airport. The output from the new API source I am polling from is rather complicated, however, with various tiers of indentation. I have not worked with Python very long and tutorials and guides online have either been for other languages (Java or C++ mostly) or have not worked for my specific case.

First off, here is the structure of the JSON that I am receiving:

[image: screenshot of JSON structure]

I underlined the values I am trying to extract. They are listed under the `OBSERVATIONS` section, associated with `precip_accum_24_hour_value_1`, `wind_gust_value_1`, `wind_cardinal_direction_value_1d`, and so on. The issue is there are two values underneath each observation so the script I have tried isn't returning the values I want. Here is the code I have tried:

```
import urllib.request
import json

f = urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.synopticdata.com/v2/stations/latest?token=8c96805fbf854373bc4b492bb3439a67&stid=KSTC&complete=1&units=english&output=json')

json_string = f.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)

for each in parsed_json['STATION']:
    observations = each['OBSERVATIONS']

print(observations)
```

This prints out everything underneath the `OBSERVATIONS` in the JSON as expected, as one long string.

```
{'precip_accum_24_hour_value_1': {'date_time': '2018-12-06T11:53:00Z', 'value': 0.01}, 'wind_gust_value_1': {'date_time': '2018-12-12T01:35:00Z', 'value': 14.0},
```

to show a small snippet of the output I am receiving. I was hoping I could individually extract the values I want from this string, but everything I have attempted is not working. I would really appreciate some guidance for finishing this piece of code so I can return the values I am looking for. I realize it may be some kind of loop or special syntax.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and replace the screenshot with enough of the actual JSON input so folks can test the code in their answers—for reasons similar to what's described in [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for each in parsed_json['STATION']:
    observations = each['OBSERVATIONS']
    for k, v in observations.items():
        print(k, v["value"])
```

JSON maps well into python's dictionary and list types, so accessing substructures can be done with `a[<index-or-key>]` syntax. Iteration over key-value pairs of a dictionary can be done as I've shown above. If you're not familiar with dictionaries in python yet, I'd recommend reading about them. Searching online should yield a lot of good tutorials.

Does this help?

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for! I appreciate your insight into the syntax to get where I need. Again I'm a total newbie at this so this was really helpful.

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you say the JSON is complicated, it really is just nested dictionaries within the main JSON response. You would access them in the same way as you would the initial JSON blob:

```
import urllib.request
import json

f = urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.synopticdata.com/v2/stations/latest?token=8c96805fbf854373bc4b492bb3439a67&stid=KSTC&complete=1&units=english&output=json')

json_string = f.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)

for each in parsed_json['STATION']:
    for value in each:
        print(value, each[value])
```

Comment: I know JSON isn't "complicated" per se to someone with experience but I'm a total newbie and this is my first attempt at a JSON with this level of nesting. I figured it was just a loop within a loop but I wasn't sure the exact syntax I was looking for. I'll give this a try, big thank you!

Comment: @BradHahn nothing meant by it, hope you can enjoy working with python/JSON!